# How to define an object as type Tilemap?

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is my reference:

[image]

And this is the error:
[image]

This persists with Tilemap and UnityEngine.Tilemap as the type.

Answer (score 0):

The [Tilemap](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.html) class is in the UnityEngine.Tilemaps namespace.

Try:

```
[SerializeField]
private UnityEngine.Tilemaps.Tilemap tm;
```